# Redux check array if object match update object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```js
const initialState = {
    cart: []
}


export default function(state = initialState, action){
    
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CART_ADDITEM':
        return { 
            ...state,
            cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
        }

        case 'CART_REMOVEITEM':
        return {
            ...state,
            cart: state.cart.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
        }
        break;
        }
    return state;
}
```

here's my add/remove to array functions

this is the object in the array.

```
id(pin): "001"
Name(pin): "Dab on them"
price(pin): 100
img(pin): "/static/media/001.ac043cfc.png"
rarity(pin): "rare"
size(pin): "S"
quantity(pin): 1
```

how to check when adding a new item to the array if object match and if it does update quantity + 1.

same thing goes for removing item from array if quantity > 1 then quantity -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if is already present in the array an object with the same id and in which quantity. In that case update the quantity, otherwise add the object to the array.

I would write few helper methods to keep everything clear and separate.

You can check for presence by quantity with something like this:

```
const quantityForItem = (list, newItem) => {
  const item = list.find(item => item.id === newItem.id)
  return item && item.quantity || 0
}
```

You can increase or decrease the quantity of an item remapping the list and alterating the interested item:

```
const updateQuantity = (list, newItem, variation) =>
  list.map(item => {
    if ( item.id !== newItem.id ) return item
    return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + variation }
  })
```

You can add a new item just concating it to the previous list. Pay attention: `concat`, not `push`, because we need to keep it immutable.

```
const add = (list, newItem) =>
  list.concat(newItem)
```

The removal of an item could be like the one you already have:

```
const remove = (list, itemToRemove) =>
  list.filter(item => item.id !== itemToRemove.id)
```

Putting everything together:

```
case 'CART_ADDITEM': {
  const { cart } = state
  const newItem = action.payload
  if ( quantityForItem(cart, newItem) !== 0 ) {
    return { cart: updateQuantity(cart, newItem, +1) }
  }
  return { cart: add(cart, newItem) }
}

case 'CART_REMOVEITEM': {
  const { cart } = state
  const itemToRemove = action.payload
  if ( quantityForItem(cart, itemToRemove) > 1 ) {
    return { cart: updateQuantity(cart, itemToRemove, -1) }
  }
  return { cart: remove(cart, itemToRemove) }
}
```

Comment: It works fine but there's one thing i forgot to mention. ids are not unique for example i can have 2 items with same id but diffrent sizes so i want it to check for ids and size to update the quantity instead of id only.

Comment: or i can just fix a unique id (id+size) which is better?

Comment: Both solutions are good. You may have a method that given an object is able to compute its unique id (maybe with id + size) and use it in the comparisons.